# Looping through $id to generate customized unique page data from Firebase backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am creating a blog in AngularJS and Firebase.
The problem I am running into is that I am trying to succesfully render unique page data when a user clicks on a link to a specific blog post which is written to firebase in the backend.

My firebase data is on "https:ngblogapp.firebaseio.com/posts"

Here is a visual of my library[image]

I am rendering the page links with ng-repeat="post in posts" where posts refers to the firebase library. 
Here is a visual of that. [image]

When I click on one of the links I get to a page with a unique url id at  as such ''' http://localhost:7000/#/post/-K0T3PqoCBVygt_LCCHF ''' but the unique page displays the data as such [image]

Let me take you into my javascript.

```
var app=angular.module('myBlogApp',
[
'ngRoute',
'app.controllers',
'app.directives',
'firebase'
])
.constant('FBURL', "https://ngblogapp.firebaseio.com/posts") //fburl
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: '../views/posts.html',
        controller: 'postController'
    }).when('/post/:postId',{
        templateUrl:'../views/singlepost.html',
        controller: 'postController'
    }).when('/page/:postId',{
        templateUrl:'../views/page.html',
        controller: 'postController' //'PageController'
    }).when('/create',{
        templateUrl:'../views/createaPost.html',
        controller:'postController'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}
]);
app.factory("Blog",["$firebaseArray","$routeParams",   function($firebaseArray, $routeParams){

var ref = new Firebase("https://ngblogapp.firebaseio.com/posts");//  FIREBASE OBJ  
var blogPostsArray = $firebaseArray(ref);
  return{

    id: $routeParams.postId,

    allPosts: blogPostsArray, // all fb objects

    addPost: function(newpost){
      newpost.datetime = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
      return blogPostsArray.$add(newpost); //push to array
    }

};

}]);



app.controller('postController',["$scope",     "$location","$routeParams","Blog","FBURL", "$firebaseObject"    ,function($scope,$location,$routeParams,Blog,FBURL,$firebaseObject){

$scope.posts = Blog.allPosts; //All blog posts
var postId = $routeParams.postId;

if(postId){
$scope.selectedPost = getPost(postId);
}

function getPost(postId){
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + postId);
return $firebaseObject(ref);
}

$scope.addPost = function(newpost){
Blog.addPost($scope.newpost);
//$location.path('/'); //redirects to home page
console.log(newpost);
console.log($scope.posts); // all posts
$scope.newpost ={}; //reset the message
};

$scope.currentPost = function(postId){
Blog.getPost(postId);
console.log(postId);
};

}]);
```

In the 'postController' I have a method called getPost(postId) which takes a parameter postId. 
my postId is assgined assigned to a routeParam like so postId = $routeParams.id.

In my html partial I am looping through posts.$id like so:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-offset-9 col-md-3">
<!--span(class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true")-->
<input type="text" ng-model="searchPost" placeholder="Search"  class="form-control"/>
</div>
<article ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: searchPost | orderBy:  date:'medium' ">
<h1 class="page-header"><a ng-href="#/post/{{post.$id}}">{{post.title}}
    <h3>{{post.text | limitTo: 30}}{{post.text.length > 30? "...": ""}}         <i>{{post.datetime | date:short}}</i></h3></a></h1>
</article>
</div>
```

Again, this renders the id on the url but directs me to a funky object

`{"$id":"posts-K0T3PqoCBVygt_LCCHF","$priority":null,"$value":null}`

I don't know what are the right API calls to get the unique id of an object and display its contents with AngularFire. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Maybe the [AngularFire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) could help here? The "funky object" is a synchronized record in a $firebaseArray collection. The `$id` property is the record's key so you can pass that as your parameter. Unclear what your question is here. The code looks okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing one slash

```
var postId = $routeParams.postId;
```

based on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams it returns an object of values of the parameters without slash

```
function getPost(postId){
    // FBURL + postId = ...firebaseio.com/posts-K0T3PqoCBVygt_LCCHF
    // FBURL + '/' + postId = ...firebaseio.com/posts/-K0T3PqoCBVygt_LCCHF
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + postId);
    return $firebaseObject(ref);
}
```

So IMHO the fix is `new Firebase(FBURL + '/' + postId)`, but I couldn't test it (or reproduce).

Comment: Generally speaking, prefer .child( postId ) or use url encoding on the parameter before concatenating it to the new Firebase(...) call (which only accepts valid, escaped URLs)

Comment: I'm glad I helped... but what @Kato is suggesting is even better ;-). That would look like this:  `(new Firebase(FBURL)).child(postId)`. If you would have a factory for `new Firebase(FBURL)` it is even simpler.